# Duda al trabajar en el background de Android en un proyecto de Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

estoy practicando y aprendiendo Xamarin y para ello me he puesto a hacer una aplicación de una agenda. Para recordar al usuario de las tareas que tiene programadas, utilizo en un segundo hilo un método que va comprobando cada 4 minutos las fechas de las tareas y depende cual sea la fecha lanzar una notificación o no. Bueno pues el tema es, que al dejar la aplicación en segundo plano parece que deja de comprobar las tareas ya que no lanza notificaciones. No se si hay algún método o opción para evitar que android se cargue la aplicación que esta en backgound.

Gracias.

Comment: Has probado con un servicio?